# How get the header of the first http request when I launch an angular app (http://localhost:4200/)

Tags: angular, http, header, angular-http-interceptors

I am looking to get the header of the first http request http://localhost:4200/

To launch my app, I go to the url http://localhost:4200/ and I want to write  the header of the http entring, in the console.

Does anyone know if it is possible ?

I try use an interceptor but I intercept only the http request and response sorting of my app.

Comment: Why do you need http Header?

Comment: any updates ? Did you find out how to get first request headers ?

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I am guessing this is simply not possible

Comment: I cannot believe that only 4 people need that feature...

Answer (score 0):

Angular [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http#httpclient) by default observes the result only, you can use `{observe: 'response'}` to get full response and get headers from the same.

```
 this.http.get('/', { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response.headers.get('SAMPLEITEM'))
 });
```

Documented [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Comment: actually you make a call to yourself here hoping that the header response wont change ..